# Any better way of storing/querying a specific tree structure in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, indexing

[image]

We got this data model. Knowing the limited tree depth, our current tables are 1:1 to the model, with foreign keys to the parent node. `Channel` to `Station`, `Measurement` to `Channel` and `Station`. 90% of the queries is:

```
select value from measurements where
fk_station=X and fk_channel=Y and timestamp>=A and timestamp<=B
order by timestamp asc
```

The rest 10% is similar on the other timestamped tables, only simpler due to missing `fk_channel`.

**Problem we are facing:** there is hundreds of millions of unique `[station,channel,timestamp]` rows in `Measurement` table and growing. The timestamp index was alredy so huge and the ordering clause so slow that we had to start splitting it per *Station Id*; so we have tables `Measurement_<Station Id>` and the `Station` foreign key is left out. It helped significantly, but still some tables got tens of millions rows. In load peaks we got around 80000 queries/minute and queries on these bigger tables are observably lazier. We still run from one MySQL/ISAM instance without any fancy optimization hacks. About 150GB on the filesystem.

1. is there any significantly different/better way to store such data model?
2. with the current structure, is it normal that we got this kind of performance hiccups with this size/load? The machine is today's average hw, no embedded atom neither 8+ core beast
3. was the splitting of `Measurement` table the right thing to do? We are no SQL gurus, but the query and the required index seemed so obvious that we didn't even consider "optimizing" it. Splitting helped a lot, but something else might too
4. is there any other way of speeding up the index? It's kinda stupid that we must do the same index walking over and over, getting subsets of the same result. We won't ever use any other indexing, not even change to `desc`. It's very specialized appliance. Would be nice if the index is somehow "native order" :-)
5. would it help to distribute/shard the splitted `Measurement` tables? As i said, some tables are still huge and the problem *feels* to be about the index size which distribution won't help, so perhaps just lowering the query load...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple rules to think about in relational dbs like mysql:

1. Fetching too much data is never fast. Aggregating it can be. - your sample query is not aggregating anything. Makes me wonder if you crunch and aggregate those **value** in you application. Hint: Aggregate using column store engine eg. infinidb, it supports parallelism in query execution too, innodb doesn't.
2. Sorting huge amount of data is never fast - ask yourself, if the query returns 100K records, how much does your crunching job/frontend grid etc consumes ? Can a web user consume 100K data on screen. Not really, then LIMIT it. Moreover sort by auto increment ID instead of timestamp. Relational db engines are not good for sorting huge chucks of data, you will hit ceiling soon.

Comment: 1. Aggregation is not an option, we need all those data. The only alternative would be implementing some kind of downsampling in a stored procedure, which is way beyond what we want to throw at the problem.

Comment: 2. The query returns max on the order of 10000 rows. It's all fed as-is to the frontend graphing package - which does the decimation mentioned in bullet 1. But i am genuinely interested in the "sort by ID" - we can imagine post-sorting at the frontend side. Does it mean that we won't need the index even for the timestamp range [A,B] selection?

Comment: "Relational db engines are not good for sorting huge chucks of data" surprising news for me (SQL guru i am not). Can you point me to some enligtening reading about the matter?

Comment: 2. Do you have clustered index/primary key on timestamp? If not, try to write the same query so that you use the primary key.

Comment: I wrote some sample query, may be it might give you some idea as to how to play around [clustered index](http://nikeshikari.blogspot.se/2012/10/rewrite-to-use-clustered-index.html).

Comment: But for the "timestamp>=A and timestamp<=B" condition, we still need the timestamp index right? Even if not clustered. We use MyISAM so far, so no clustered unless we switch to InnoDB. Though timestamp IS our primary key, but it doesn't mean anything particular on MyISAM with regards to the physical storage.

Comment: Could you guess which approach will give us the biggest performance boost? 1. leave index as-is, don't ORDER BY, sort at client side (PHP) 2. switch to InnoDB with clustered index on timestamp 3. apply your workaround to clustered index

Comment: Short term perf gain option-(1). Long term gain - think over your problem again "Can I plot with less sampling and still convey the same info?", "Can I do ajax, as user interacts with a part of graph". ps: i have no clue abt your app, i am just throwing broad ideas

Comment: Just interleaving the set at fixed delta (aka less sampling) is not acceptable. It's weather logging so uneven spikes are likely and very important to see. As i said, only a clever decimation (Douglas-Pecker etc.) implemented with SQL powers would be acceptable. Anyway, we are going to try switch to InnoDB (for other reasons too) and see what the cluster index does for us.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility that splitting up Measurement data over more than one table can reduce the size? If 90% of the queries are over the last 24 hours of timestamps, then you might want to finetune that data, and store the rest in a separate table or even database. I believe the Measurement should have a FK only to Channel, which has only its ID as PK, and an FK to Station.

Comment: I didn't say that 90% are limited to the last X hours :-) Quite opposite so. Very popular queries are like "give me the current month for years 2012-2009".